# Using C18 compiler on MPLAB X on with Wine

Tags: macos, embedded, wine, mplab-c18

I have been wanting to use the C18 Compiler on MAC OS X for a long while for my MPLAB projects, (so as I can use the mdd library), but it isn't available except for Windows. So I have installed Wine and have installed the compiler through it, and have added the compiler to the toolchain in MPLAB X, i cannot get a simple program to build. I get the following error:

> /Users/me/Wine Files/drive_c/Program Files/Microchip/mplab
> 18/v3.47/bin/mcc18.exe: cannot execute binary file

Does anybody know a) what this exactly means and b) HOW I should solve this?

I should add, I am using MPLAB X for OS X , not the windows version in wine. I tried to use the windows version, I installed it and everything , tried opening it in wine but it wouldn't even open....

Comment: So you want to cross compile for Windows on Mac?

Comment: @GrantGarrison I want to compile for my pic18 micros with the C18 compiler...which I can't natively do on a Mac....so...yes?..

Comment: any chance that you would be willing to use a VM?

Comment: @GrantGarrison yes if it solves my problem!

Comment: what if you were to compile on Windows, then send the file to your Mac?

Comment: @GrantGarrison Well Im using mac so I would ideally compile on the mac.  I have tried installing a windows version of MPLAB X and using it with wine but I couldn't get it to run!

Comment: @GrantGarrison I dont have access to a windows pc..

Comment: use a Windows VM, not a Windows PC. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: @GrantGarrison Cheers, I shall try this and see how I get on!